# asp.net requiredfieldvalidator clientside validate multiple groups

Tags: asp.net

I have a form with 3 asp textboxes for changing password - old password, new password and confirm password and a submit button on form. Old password is checked first for setting new password. The scenario is if administrator wants to change the password it will not check any old password, while for user it will check old password, if it is correct then set the new password. I have taken two requiredfiledvalidator controls for old password and new password field and comparevalidator control to check confirm password.

I have assigned groupA for old password required field validator, and groupB for new and confirm password. The scenario is for admin login I hides old password as it is not required and for user login I makes it visible.

So problem here is that for user login submit event I want to validate both groupA and groupB. Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep same `groupname` for all controls. Set `Enabled=false` to RequiredFieldValidator when user role is `Admin`.

Comment: Thanks buddy.. I don't know how can I forget that simple thing? :) Thanks again..